# 2002 Chevy Blazer - Oil in coolant

Tags: engine, chevrolet, head-gasket, blazer

I have a 2002 Chevy Blazer with 237755 miles.

I was just informed that I have a blown head gasket and oil is leaking into my coolant. On my way into work this morning my check engine light was blinking (this is the second time this has happened). I don't have the money to purchase a new car nor do I want to spend the money to get everything repaired on my car. (Total estimate of $4,071.25 including labor)

How long will my car last?

Is there any way I can prolong this issue until I can afford to buy another car?

Comment: Unfortunately I know many people in your situation. Vehicle has huge mileage,  it's plumb wore out and you have no money in your pocket. With that many miles on the odometer just fixing the head gasket may not be enough to get the car running again. What shape is the transmission in?  Not much anyone here can do for you. We share your pain.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a blown headgasket, it won't last long - a few miles at most. Keep going too long as the engine will overheat and sieze up, and then you'll need a new engine.

I'd suggest you get a few more quotes - You don't state where you are in the world, but the gaskets themselves are cheap, and it shouldn't need much more than half a day's labour - around here it is about £4-500, so maybe US$6-800 for a back-street garage to do the job.